# Extjs4, update editor grid cell value and sync store

Tags: extjs4.1

I update editor grid cell value (textfield) in controller and try to sync store but the store does not update the updated row. I think the store couldn't recognize the cell has been updated.

in controller, I did like this,

```
this.getMyGrid().store.each(function (item) {
    if (!item.data.testField) {
    item.set('testFeild', "UPDATED");
    item.commit();
    }
});

this.getMyGrid().store.sync();
```

then, it update cell value as well, but it couldn't sync();

anybody know, what I am doing wrong, please advice me.

Thanks

Comment: Does your model have a `testField` field?

Comment: @Izhaki yes, it has. So update the cell manually one by one then the sync works well.

Comment: Any chance your condition `!item.data.testField` always fails? Do you get `console.log()` if you put such within the if condition?

Comment: @Izhaki The condition is ok, I check with console.log() also on screen it show updated value. but there are no the red mark (I don't know what call is it, once update cell value, there is a red triangle mark on top left on the cell). If manually update cell, the red mark show up on the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without  ***item.commit();***, it works fine :)